# Ready made beans to connect MySQL by jdbc?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, javadoc, mysql-connector

Can I just load com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource class as a bean in Spring? What are this class API? Where it can be found?

I can only find samples of JNDI usage.

Are there any ready-made beans to have such properties like `driverName`, `connectionString` `userName`, `password` and which allow to issue SQL statements?

**EDIT 1**

Sorry forgot to say that I need solution except with `DriverManagerDataSource` because it is said manual it is very basic and not suitable for J2EE containers.

Comment: I've added to my answer.  You can use any `DataSource` - you are not limited to `DriverManagerDataSource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 13.3.1 of the Spring User Guide, titled [Data access with JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-connections), shows how to create a bean to access a database.  You specify username, password, driver class, url, etc., to create a bean representing a `DataSource`.

You can use any data source class here, not only the `DriverManagerDataSource` shown in the example at the link above.  For example, we deploy to Tomcat so I use `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` as our data source.  If you're using Tomcat you can read more about that pool here: [The Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)